# how to receive packet thru WiFi

Tags: android, tcp, android-wifi

I have some PC application that send some information to my android application using WIFI ( the PC application using the WIFI network to send simple TCP binary message ).

On my android application i want to receive this binary stream ( and after     receiving - to do something with the message ( after de-Serialization ))

1. How can i receive this message on the android side ?
2. How can i open on my android application the WiFi port to receive this message ?

Comment: You will need to create server on any of the device on particular port say 8089. then open connection from client on the same port after WIFI connection. Your Android device must be connected to PC using WIFI before opening TCP connection.

Comment: How to connect between them ? They are listen to the same WiFi network.  or maybe i did not understood something

Comment: You can create Server on any of the device. And then connect to that server using IP/PORT from client. that should work If both the devices are connected through WIFI network.

Comment: First try PING from client to server.(Ping must not be disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was better to write this as a comment. But unfortunately I don't have enough reputation. But I guess this tutorial will work for you. [Here](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com.tr/2014/06/android-tcpip-client-server-socket.html)

I found some more examples but don't want to link them all here. Just googled Android TCP Server. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=ie7&q=android%20tcp%20server&rls=com.microsoft:tr:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&rlz=1I7LENN_trTR498TR498&gws_rd=ssl)